# Can we cancel/refund an order made with "Amazon Pay" within Seller Central?

Tags: orders, amazon-pay, amazonsellercentral

Can we cancel or refund an order made with "Amazon Pay" within Seller Central?

After looking to the AMAZON PAY documentation and Seller Central guide I couldn't find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cancel and refund orders through Seller Central. To do so, log in, then hover over orders in the top navigation and click `Manage Transactions`.

[image: Manage Transactions]

On the **Manage Transactions** page, find the order you want to take action on, then click on the drop down in the **Action** column -- both Cancel Order and Refund are available, depending on the state of the order.

[image: Cancel Payment]

[image: Refund Payment]